# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project angular-ssr-example

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I Have a Angular with spring boot application, but when I run, I get the below error. I searched in google, but didn't find any solution.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project angular-ssr-example: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbH1m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message already tells you the reason. You are probably running maven with a JRE instead of a JDK. Check the eclipse preferences at "Installed JREs". If there is no JDK to select, install a JDK from the Oracle homepage and select it in this window. Then the compilation should work.